# How does WooCommerce store products / product variations? / Free Script to import product variations?

Tags: plugins

So I'm just working for a client right now importing CSVs of products to WooCommerce.  I've imported a lot of products so far using an existing plugin, but don't want to buy the CSV Product Import Suite for $99 to import product variations.

So... Can anyone help me to answer one of the following two questions:

1. Does anyone know a free WooCommerce plugin / script that will let me import product variations?
2. If not, can anyone explain to me HOW WooCommerce stores product variations in the MySQL database, so that I can write a script to import product variations?

Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is not as extensive as the woo product but works very well and you can easily
modify it. Good luck.
By the way, today, and I don't know for how long, woo is having a 50% discount on their plugins. Just go to their site.

Here's your plugin link

https://github.com/dgrundel/woo-product-importer/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

I searched for a free script to import variation for quite a while when migrating a customer from WP e-commerce and wasn't able to find one. If you do please post a link here.

As far as your second question, products are custom posts with variations being children of the parent product. Just like any other post in WordPress.

Comment: I'm curious, what made you or your client switch?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah In my opinion Woo simply was a better fit for the client and seemed to be better documented